# Parsing item page for an online shop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In this function I'm parsing the page of the item in the online shop. Some items lack the picture, some lack price etc, so there are few `if-else` checks.

My questions are:

1. How to get rid of these ugly `if-else` checks?
2. How I can "pythonize" my code further?
3. Is it correct? I.e when I manipulate the variable value using previously assigned value:

   ```
   name = soup.find('span',{"class":"project_name"})
   if name is not None:
       name = re.sub(r'[«,»]','', name.text)
   ```

Below is my full code:

```
def grab_properties(url,html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    link = soup.find('iframe', {"src":"e.smth.com"})

    if link is not None:
        link = link.get("src")
        id = re.match(".*\[(\w+)\].*", link).group(1)
        if id is not None:
            if id not in ids:
                name = soup.find('span',{"class":"project_name"})
                if name is not None:
                    name = re.sub(r'[«,»]','', name.text)
                    if (soup.find('img',{"id":"item0image"}) is not None):
                        img_url = soup.find('img',{"id":"item0image"}).get('src')
                        price = soup.find('span',{"class":"project_price"})
                        if price is not None:
                            price = price.text
                            price = re.sub(u'[руб,\., ]','', price)
                        else:
                            price =u"Call us!"
                        return [id.encode('utf8'), name.encode('utf8'), url.encode('utf8'), img_url.encode('utf8'), price.encode('utf8')]
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview.SE! I think we are missing the definition for (at least) `ids`. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, this is a global variable to control which items have been already added to the output file. I only pasted code for the function to make it easier to follow the logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get rid of those if-else checks, but you can get rid of the nesting. For example:

```
if foo:
    if bar:
        return foo + bar
```

could be flattened to

```
if not foo:
    return None
if not bar:
    return None
return foo + bar
```

While this is is in fact longer, such code tends to be easier to read.

If we apply that to your code (and fix some style issues like putting a space after *each* comma), then we end up with:

```
def grab_properties(url, html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    link = soup.find('iframe', {"src": "e.smth.com"})
    if link is None:
        return None
    link = link.get("src")

    id = re.match(".*\[(\w+)\].*", link).group(1)
    if (id is None) or (id in ids):
        return None

    name = soup.find('span', {"class": "project_name"})
    if name is None:
        return None
    name = re.sub(r'[«,»]', '', name.text)

    image_element = soup.find('img', {"id": "item0image"})
    if image_element is None:
        return None
    img_url = image_element.get('src')

    price = soup.find('span', {"class": "project_price"})
    if price is None:
        price = u"Call us!"
    else
        price = re.sub(u'[руб,\., ]', '', price.text)

    return [attr.encode('utf8') for atr in (id, name, url, img_url, price)]
```

Notice that I created the `image_element` variable to avoid searching for the same element multiple times, that I used a list comprehension to encode various strings to UTF-8, and that I used empty lines to separate the code for unrelated attributes, thus making the code easier to understand. I also swapped the `if price is not None` condition around to avoid a confusing negation.

We should now talk about regular expressions (see also the [`re` library documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)). The `[…]` is a *character class*. It matches any of the contained characters, so `[abc]` will match either *a* or *b* or *c*, but not the whole string `abc`. The comma is not special inside a character class, so `[«,»]` will match left or right guillemets, or a comma. To match just the angled quotation marks, use `[«»]`. Similarly, `[руб,\., ]` will match either *р* or *у* or *б* or a comma or a period or a space. Note that inside a character class, the period is not a metacharacter and does not have to be escaped. So that charclass would be equivalent to `[р,у б.]` (the order of characters does not matter). If you want to match alternative patterns, use the `|` regex operator: `руб|[. ]`, which matches either the substring `руб` or a period or a space.

You could also consider precompiling your regular expressions, which might improve performance if you call your function very often:

```
RE_GUILLEMETS = re.compile('[«»]')

def ...:
    ...
    name = RE_GUILLEMETS.sub('', name.text)
```